# DockPanel changes color background when clicked

Tags: c#, wpf

I set a background color for a `DockPanel`, but it changes when it is accidentally `clicked`. How to detach this behaviour from the `dockpanel`?

There is no `IsPressed` properties or similar, so I can't use this:

```
<Style  TargetType="{x:Type DockPanel}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This is a `DockPanel` used in the main window:

```
<DockPanel>
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" 
               Text="Margins : "/>
    <Image Source="/View/Bitmaps/Horizontal.bmp"/>
    <TextBox  Style="{StaticResource EditBarStyle}" 
              Text="{Binding ReportHorizontalMargin}"/>
    <Image Source="/View/Bitmaps/Vertical.bmp"/>
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource EditBarStyle}"  
             Text="{Binding ReportVerticalMargin}"/>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right"  
            Command="{Binding UpdateReportMargins}">
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"  
                   Text="Modify"/>
    </Button>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Show your `DockPanel` too.

Comment: It's not due to `DockPanel` .. it does not have `appearance`

Comment: So, how can i solve this problem? I use the dockpanel to show other items and when the user accidentaly press the background it changes color to blu.

Comment: The same happens with StackPanel

Comment: @Dukenukem show your code demo ... Problem relates with items in `DockPanel` ...

Comment: DockPanel xaml added

Comment: are you sure it's the dockpanel and not another control inside the dockpanel?  it could inherit this behaviour from a parent

Comment: Nowhere in my code there is a control that changes background color on click.

Comment: used `style` information is still missing .. @Dukenukem .. you are beginner in `wpf` right?

Comment: This `DockPanel` is placed as a direct child of a `Window`? Or is placed in another element? Maybe if you share some more code we could help you. For now when I placed your code as a direct child of a window (without your custom styles of course) I couldn't reproduce described behavior.

Comment: In the style of an object i define things like FontSize, BorderThickness, Alignments etc. I assume that these things don't affect the behaviour of a container when clicked. Here I am trying to tell that the empty part of a container (a DockPanel, StackPanel, Grid, ecc.) changes color when clicked.

Comment: Again... In what control your `DockPanel` (etc...) is placed? Maybe you can provide code for whole view? From this piece of xaml we cannot say anything more.

Answer (score 3):

### To answer your specific question

> How to detach this behaviour from the dockpanel?

There is an important feature that is handy to know in WPF that a Background of `NULL` of a control (i.e.`<Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>`) is different to a background that is transparent (i.e. `<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>`) with regard to hit-testing, even though visually they look the same.

Hit-testing and thus firing mouse events happens if the background is `Transparent` but not if the background is `{x:Null}`, so setting your background to `{x:Null}` will have the effect you are asking for.

### Why is the background changing colour?

The standard `DockPanel` does not have this feature and I  cannot deduce where this could be happening with the code snippets you have here.

Could this be the `TextBox` control showing blue when all the text is selected?

Have you tried viewing the application running via [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)?

Once you point Snoop at your application running then you can select the rectangle region that is changing colour (move the mouse over you application holding down `CTRL` and `Shift`) or select the control on the Snoop panel Tree View.  Snoop will then Adorn the control with a Red-ish border.

Identifying the control specifically responsible for that region of the screen might help you narrow down where the problem is.